# angular 4 - use correct this inside of jquery

Tags: angular

I am using jquery's `ui-sortable` inside `ngOnInit` which works fine, however after update I want to call a service method, but there `this` does not refer to the component class, so how to make it refer to component class?

```
$('tbody').sortable({

        items: "tr:not('.home')",
        placeholder: "ui-state-hightlight",
        update: function () {
            var ids = $('tbody').sortable("serialize");
            this.pagesService.postReorderPages(ids).subscribe(); // how to make THIS here refer to current component class?
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`arrow` syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead of `function()`:

```
$('tbody').sortable({

    items: "tr:not('.home')",
    placeholder: "ui-state-hightlight",
    update: () => {
        var ids = $('tbody').sortable("serialize");
        this.pagesService.postReorderPages(ids).subscribe(); // now `this` should refers to the component class
    }

});
```

Or you can just add `bind(this)` after the `function()`:

```
$('tbody').sortable({

    items: "tr:not('.home')",
    placeholder: "ui-state-hightlight",
    update: function() {
        var ids = $('tbody').sortable("serialize");
        this.pagesService.postReorderPages(ids).subscribe(); // now `this` should refers to the component class
    }.bind(this)

});
```

Comment: arrow function seems to do it, binding does not, thank you!

Comment: while you are here, any idea why `this.pagesService.postReorderPages(ids);` sends proper values and `this.pagesService.postReorderPages(ids).subscribe(res => {
                    console.log(res);
                });` sends an empty object? The `ids` variable has proper value in the first example but is an empty object in the second example.

Comment: @VojislavKovacevic in `this.pagesService.postReorderPages(ids).subscribe(res => { console.log(res); });` statement, which one holds empty object, the `ids` or the `res`?

Comment: ids. it kind of works if in the service method I put ids inside object like so `return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/pages/reorder-pages', {ids})` , I do get the correct values but the whole thing is a bit different (not valid json) so it doesn't work. Anyway I believe just passing ids should be able to work somehow.

Comment: Once again i want to repeat that inside the service method `console.log(ids);` logs correct value, but then when I pass it as an argument in the line after `return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/pages/reorder-pages', ids)
            .map(res => res.json());` express gets an empty object.  Also if instead of angular post I do jquery ajax post like so `$.post(url, ids);` it works fine.

Comment: @VojislavKovacevic I'm so sorry, I'm afraid currently I don't have any solution for this `ids` problem :(

Comment: I think it's because it is inside of the jquery plugin, it's giving me more problems. Thanks for the help btw.